# Sending empty response with MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to send back an empty response back to the caller, when using `MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway`?
I know with MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway, there is an explicit method to allow empty responses, but I don't see one for inbound. Googling doesn't get me any results, either

Answer (score 1):

The `ignoreEmptyResponses` is only relevant to the `SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway`.
See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Specify whether empty String response payloads should be ignored.
 * The default is <code>true</code>. Set this to <code>false</code> if
 * you want to send empty String responses in reply Messages.
 * @param ignoreEmptyResponses true if empty responses should be ignored.
 */
public void setIgnoreEmptyResponses(boolean ignoreEmptyResponses)
```

As far as I know there is no way to send something like `null` with a marshaller.

You probably should just send some special POJO back into a reply and WS client should done something with that one.